# gcm quick start sample can't retrieve token

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I worked step by step through [the tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/start?configured=true) on google to try google notifications

I typed the `APP_KEY` correctly, but when I build the app and run it on my device application it says:

> an error occurred while either fetching the instanceID token, sending the fetched token to the server or subscribing to the pubsub topic. please try running the sample again

How do I resolve this error?

Comment: You should include the exact error message you got (rather than retyping it), along with the exact procedure you used to obtain the error.

Comment: The error message received indicates that the `broadcastReceiver.onReceive` wasn't able to send the token (returned `false`). As the error suggests, you can try running the sample again to see if it will be okay on the second attempt. If there are logs you can provide, it would be help for the community.

Comment: its now work .. perfectly .. just by time :) :) thnx bro's

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **Server API key** (not the client API key in googleservices.json) is provided as the value of **API_KEY** in **GcmSender.java**.

Also make sure that you have the latest updates of Google Play Service and Google Repository in you Android SDK.